# Обернуть внутрь div цикл php

Tags: php, html, циклы, while

Есть следующий код:

```
<div class="news_post">
<?php 
while($article = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
  echo '<div class="news_login">';
  echo $article['login'];
  echo  '</div>';
  echo '<div class="news_title">';
  echo  $article['title']. '<br>';
  echo '</div>';  
  echo "<img src='" . $article['picture'] . "' alt='' class='news_img'/>";
  echo '<div class="news_descr">';
  echo $article['descr']. '<br>';
  echo '</div>';
  echo '</div>';
}
?>
</div>
```

Задача состоит в том, чтобы обернуть всё, что находится в цикле, в отдельный блок "news_wrapper".
Через echo как на примере не получается, т.к оборачивается только $article['login'] и всё.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо выкинуть все ненужные `echo` из цикла и правильно выставить отступы в html-разметке. Тогда станет понятно что и куда добавлять:

```
<div class="news_post">
<?php
while($article = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){?>
    <div class="news_wrapper">
        <div class="news_login">
            <?=$article['login']?>
        </div>
        <div class="news_title">
            <?=$article['title']?>
        </div>
        <img src="<?=$article['picture']?>" alt="" class='news_img'/>
        <div class="news_descr">
            <?=$article['descr']?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php
}?>
</div>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 0):

В начале цикла открываете тег, в конце закрываете...

```
<div class="news_post">
<?php 
while($article = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
  echo '<div class="news_wrapper">';
  echo '<div class="news_login">';
  echo $article['login'];
  echo  '</div>';
  echo '<div class="news_title">';
  echo  $article['title']. '<br>';
  echo '</div>';  
  echo "<img src='" . $article['picture'] . "' alt='' class='news_img'/>";
  echo '<div class="news_descr">';
  echo $article['descr']. '<br>';
  echo '</div>';
  echo '</div>';
  echo '</div>';
}
</div>
```